# If A is idempotent and $A^5=3A^3-2A$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Stuck at this question for a while.

Question : If A is idempotent and $A^5=3A^3-2A$ , Prove $A=0$

My try :

By $A^2-A=0$ , we know that the minimal polynomial devides $\Rightarrow x(x-1)$

So the options for the minimal polynomial is only : $x , x-1 , x(x-1)$

I tried assuming by contradiction that the minimal polynomial is $x$ and then we get $A=0$ and we are finished.

if $x-1$ is the minimal then $A-I=0 \Rightarrow A=I$ , but we have an eigenvalue that is $0$ so $|A|=0$ and the matrix can't be $I$.

but I'm stuck with $x(x-1)$.

any hints? Thank you

Comment: can you use that $A^5-3A^3+2A=A(A^2-1)(A^2-2)=0$?

Comment: I don't think it is true. Consider $A = I_{(2)}$.

Comment: Maybe the condition is that $ A $ is Nilpotent? Can you check?

Answer (score 2):

The claim is false. Just take any nonzero idempotent matrix.

Indeed, $A^2=A$ implies $A^n=A$ for all $n\ge 1$. Therefore $A^5-3A^3+2A=A-3A+2A=0$ and so $A^5=3A^3-2A$ gives no new information.

Comment: The claim is true if $A^5=3A^3+2A$. So perhaps it was a typo.

Comment: Intersting , That's why I can't figure out what to do with the equation $A^5-3A^3+2A$ , it gives nothing new and I can't conclude the matrix is $0$.. I checked it again , I wrote exactly as in the Question

Answer (score 2):

I agree with the other answer that the claim is false, and won't repeat that argument.

However, assuming that there is a typo in the problem, and it should've been e.g. $A^5=3A^3+2A^2$... Here is a procedure that helps in problems like this one:

We know that $p(A)=0$ and $q(A)=0$, where $p(X)=X^5-3X^3-2X^2$ and $q(X)=X^2-X$. Let's do *Euclidean division of $p$ by $q$ (with a remainder)*:

$$X^5-3X^3-2X^2 = (X^2-X)(X^3+X^2-2X-4)-4X$$

So $p(X)=q(X)s(X)+r(X)$ where $s(X)=X^3+X^2-2X-4$ and $r(x)=-4X$.

This immediately implies that $r(A)=p(A)-q(A)s(A)=0-0\cdot s(A)=0$, i.e. $-4A=0$. I hope you are working in the field $\mathbb R$ (or another field of characteristic $\ne 2$), in which $-4\ne 0$ and so $A=0$.

(Note in a field of characteristic $2$ the claim is just as false as with the original problem, as in characteristic $2$ we have not really fixed the typo - the "fixed" problem is the same as the original one. This makes me think that, perhaps, there is a different typo in the original problem.)